# SELECT IN failing - large dataset

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery, where-clause

I'm attempting to evaluate how many times a transaction is started in a given month in our system for a reconciliation process.

A Transaction Reference can be created in a previous month so I am trying to exclude those transactions from the final count - the first thought was to use a "WHERE IN" type approach, but the outcome is always 0 which is definitely wrong as when I execute the queries in isolation, there are entries in the subquery which should be excluded.

I have read that "WHERE IN" type queries aren't reliable especially when there are large data sets returned in the subquery, but I don't know how to rework this one to achieve the goal in this case, and going forward if this way of doing it is flawed which it appears to be.

Current query is shown below - thanks for your help:

```
 SELECT Count(DISTINCT TransactionRef)
 FROM Payments 
 WHERE Month(PaymentDate) = 8 
 AND Year(PaymentDate) = 2011 
 AND TransactionRef NOT IN 
      (SELECT DISTINCT TransactionRef 
       FROM Payments WHERE PaymentDate < '20110801')
```

**EDIT**
OK further to answers, it seems a null value was doing me wrong... thanks - here is the edited code in case anyone stumbles here in future:

```
 SELECT Count(DISTINCT TransactionRef)
 FROM Payments 
 WHERE Month(PaymentDate) = 8 
 AND Year(PaymentDate) = 2011 
 AND TransactionRef NOT IN 
      (SELECT DISTINCT TransactionRef 
       FROM Payments WHERE TransactionRef IS NOT NULL AND PaymentDate < '20110801')
```

Comment: You probaly have a `NULL` value for `TransactionRef `. this will always cause `NOT IN` to return zero results.

Comment: BTW: where on earth did you read `"WHERE IN" type queries aren't reliable`? I suggest disregarding anything else from the same source.

Comment: Thanks :) The power of Google to completely send one off on a ridiculous tangent it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the column TransactionRef has any null in it the not in [will return false](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/18/60210.aspx).
use Exists.

if NULLs are not your problem then you'll have to give us mroe info

Comment: Thanks Mladen - this was the root of the problem - there was a NULL in there and it now works.

Comment: I tried to but it wouldn't let me until the answer was 10 mins old. Done now...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Am I completely wrong or your query is exactly the same as this one:

```
 SELECT Count(DISTINCT TransactionRef)
 FROM Payments 
 WHERE Month(PaymentDate) = 8 
 AND Year(PaymentDate) = 2011 
 AND (PaymentDate >= '20110801')
```

**Edit:** reading it again, do you want to only get those paymeents recorded in August? Then you could simply use a BETWEEN in the where.

what is your real need?

Comment: I hope not ;) Anyway, the distinction is that the subquery returns a set of transaction references that have been seen before August 2011. Each Transaction Reference may appear multiple times over time, I just need to capture the ones that appear for the first time in a given month - hence the exclusion clause.

Answer (score 0):

use not exists

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT TransactionRef)  FROM Payments  p1 

WHERE Month(PaymentDate) = 8   

AND Year(PaymentDate) = 2011   

AND not exists (SELECT 1 FROM Payments p2


                           where p2.TransactionRef =p1.TransactionRef
                           and PaymentDate < '20110801')
```